# Are single/double quotes allowed inside HTML attribute values?

Tags: html, quotes

I'm trying to set attribute value that contains a single quote:

```
var attr_value = "It's not working";
var html = "<label my_attr='" + attr_value + "'>Text</label>";
$('body').html(html);
```

However, I get the following result:

```
<label working="" not="" s="" my_attr="It">Text</label>
```

How could I fix this ?

Are double quotes allowed inside attribute values ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, both quotes are allowed in attribute values, but you must HTML-escape the quote you're using as an attribute value delimiter, as well as other HTML-special characters like `<` and `&`:

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return s.split('&').join('&amp;').split('<').join('&lt;').split('"').join('&quot;').split("'").join('&#39;');
}

var html= '<label my_attr="'+encodeHTML(attr_value)+'">Text</label>';
```

However, you are usually much better off *not* trying to hack a document together from HTML strings. You risk bugs and HTML-injection (leading to cross-site-scripting security holes) every time you forget to escape. Instead, use DOM-style methods like `attr()`, `text()` and the construction shortcut:

```
$('body').append(
    $('<label>', {my_attr: attr_value, text: 'Text'})
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a detailed answer! Just for curiosity regarding the implementation of `encodeHTML`: It can be implemented using the `replace` function, right ? Is it less effective ?

Comment: It can, sure, `replace(/&/g, '&amp;')...`. In this case it doesn't matter since the search strings can't contain any regex-special characters, but in general for plain string-replace `split`/`join` can be simpler, since you can use search strings without have to worry about regex-escaping. Comparative performance varies across browsers.

Comment: Thanks ! Could you give me a pointer to "construction shortcut" tutorial ?

Comment: As an example of @bobince’s point that you shouldn’t hack a document together from HTML strings: the backtick character ``` (which is not included in the `encodeHTML` function) can be used to escape from an [unquoted attribute value](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values) in IE. For this reason, it has been made invalid to use the backtick character in an attribute value as per “HTML5”.

Answer (score 25):

You can use single quotes inside double quotes or double quotes inside single quotes. If you want to use single quotes inside single quotes or double quotes inside double quotes, you have to HTML encode them.

Valid markup:

```
<label attr="This 'works'!" />
<label attr='This "works" too' />
<label attr="This does NOT \"work\"" />
<label attr="And this is &quot;OK&quot;, too" />
```

Comment: The one with the backslashes doesn't work. That's a JavaScript escape, not HTML.

Comment: You are right, I edited my response and removed the escaping.

Comment: You just forgot the closing `"` in `<label attr="And this is &quot;OK&quot;, too />`, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Use double-quotes as the attribute delimiter:

```
var html = "<label my_attr=\"" + attr_value + "\">Text</label>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var attr_value = "It&#39;s not working"
```