# Set double quotes string in select option value from javascript/jquery and also get from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, double-quotes

My basic requirement is to set select option value using jquery and also want to get its value.

In my PHP code, I am creating options like

```
foreach ($option_value->values as $key => $opt_value) {
      $variants_options .= '<option value="' . $variant_val . '">' . $opt_value . '</option>';
}
```

From js add this value as,

```
jQuery("#section-" + row_id + " .variant_detail_section.addFromApi .option1_options").html(value.variants_options[value.variants_name[0]]);
```

Its look like
[image: Select option display as image]

Now, I want to get value of selected

```
option1 = jQuery("#section-" + row_id + " .option1_options").find(":selected").val();
```

Here, I am getting half value

Getting: 'Pet Size Bed (40' instead 'Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")'

So, here the problem is
How can I get double quotes string?

Is there any other way to set double quote string and get it from jquery or javascript?

## UPDATE

Now I use html() for get text of selected option value.

Here my problem is I get html code of some special character like:

```
&amp; &lt;&gt; instead &,<,>
```

So How can I get special characters instead of its htmlcode?

Can I use text() or it create any issue?

Comment: You can check it : [Double quotes inside html attrbute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996653/are-single-double-quotes-allowed-inside-html-attribute-values).  Use `encodeHTML` convert  `'Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")'`.

Comment: @MinhNguyen I used that but removed because performing many operations on that after this so I need to do lots of code for manage that. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.html()` for getting the text of selected Option.

Here's an example

```js
$('#selBox').change(function(){
var selBox = $('#selBox').find(":selected").html()
console.log('Selected text value is ',selBox)
selBox = $('#selBox').find(":selected").val()
console.log('Selected actual value is ',selBox)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='selBox'>
<option value='Pet Size Bed'>Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")</option>
<option value='M'>M</option>
<option value='L'>L</option>
</select>
```

Or You can also try covering the value with single qoutes

```
<option value='Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")'>Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")</option>
```

Comment: It not right if option value doesn't like option text

Comment: In that case ,You can try covering the value with single qoutes.
<option value='Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")'>Pet Size Bed (40" X 30")</option>

Comment: @MinhNguyen Yes, you are right. But, in my case both are the same so no issue.

Comment: @Bharath Now I am using html() as you suggest. But here I  get another issue.
I will just update in question.

Comment: @tejashpatel As you mentioned in u r question, using '.text()' can be a quick fix.
But escaping Double quotes or . Giving single qoutes inside double qoutes is a proper fix

Check this Link:- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You need to add slashes before the quotes:

In your PHP code use `addslahes()` and the you will be able to get the right value.

```
foreach ($option_value->values as $key => $opt_value) {
      $variants_options .= '<option value="' . addslahes($variant_val) . '">' . $opt_value . '</option>';
}
```