# output value of json array and then sent another get request with the values

Tags: php, rest

i am really new to stackoverflow and actually dont have any clue about php.

I have a json array which looks like

`[{"betreff":"h"},{"betreff":"VS Code fehlt"}]`

i´ve created (copied :D) a foreach loop
to output the "h" and "VS Code fehlt"

```
function display_array_recursive($json_rec){

if($json_rec){
    foreach($json_rec as $key=> $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            display_array_recursive($value);
        }else{
            echo '<a href="#"  onClick="test("'.$value.'")">';
        }
    }
}
```

As we can see now the "h" and "VS Code fehlt" parts are being outputted as links. I want to make it so that whenever I click on the link a new get requests should be sent out with the giving value.

```
function test($value){when pressed = send new file_get_contents request to localhost/api/ticket/{$value}}
```

i hope i could describe good enough what i want.
Thanks in advance, please inform me if anything is unclear

Answer (score 0):

You can't use PHP to make GET requests like that (unless you use a hidden IFRAME, as far as I know). You need to use JavaScript for that, using any of those APIs (if you're using vanilla JavaScript):

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Example:

```php
<script>
    function test(url)
    {
        fetch(url);
    }
</script>

<?php

function display_array_recursive($json_rec)
{
    if (!$json_rec) {
        return;
    }
    foreach($json_rec as $key=> $value){
        if (is_array($value)) {
            display_array_recursive($value);
            continue;
        }
        echo '<a href="#" onClick="test(\''
            . htmlspecialchars(
                $value,
                ENT_QUOTES|ENT_HTML5,
                'UTF-8'
            )
            . '\')">Text</a>';
    }
}
```

Notice the function `display_array_recursive` is escaping the HTML. It's also using `'` (single quote) for the `test` arguments. It's already using `"` (double quote) for the element attribute values.

I suggest you to read:

- [How do I run PHP code when a user clicks on a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link)
- https://www.delftstack.com/howto/php/onclick-php/
- https://johnmorrisonline.com/prevent-xss-attacks-escape-strings-in-php/
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3996696/4067232
- https://betterprogramming.pub/refactoring-guard-clauses-2ceeaa1a9da